# Bug with regards to .tar.gz in Chrome when 'Asking where to save downloads'

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tar

Every time I try to download or save a .tar.gz file, I get something like this:

[image]

The popup is simply wrong, I've used the right `.tar.gz` extension. Clicking on `Use .gz` saves the file as `.tar.gz`, and clicking on `Use .tar.gz` saves the file as `.tar.tar.gz`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour of Chrome here. Does it happen to all .tar.gz files you download (from different sites) or only for one site? Did you try the download with all extensions etc. disabled?

Comment: @patrix: it does that for all sites. However, you probably need to enable "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in the Chrome preferences; the issue does not arise with the default setting of automatically downloading everything to `Downloads`.

Comment: Ah, well, got it now. But as long as you select "Use .gz" it gets saved correctly, doesn't it? Raise an issue with the Chrome team then, it's at least highly inconvenient right now.

Comment: I have this problem as well on 10.7 + Chrome 22.

Comment: Incredible, this has been around since Chrome version 11.0.696.68 on OS X 10.6 (May 2011) (see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83084) and it's still an issue in Chrome version 26.0.1410.43 on OS X 10.8! Interestingly, it is solved in Chromium (tested with version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04.)

Comment: Can you link to a publicly available file by editing the question? It's likely a problem with the web server encoding the file incorrectly and I'm guessing you don't really want an answer "No - you can't fix it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented bug:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83084

Look for a nightly build or update to potentially address this or perhaps choosing another browser. Hat tip to [jaume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/32815/jaume) for the comment alerting us to the specific issue being tracked.

Comment: The bug is marked as FIXED now. Here is hoping it will make it into Chrome soon.

Comment: I just downloaded Chrome Canary and it works ;-)